# Confusion about the proof of Poincaré lemma for Currents

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

In Demailly's "Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry" page 20 2.D.4, he proves the Poincaré lemma for Currents. The theorem states as follows:

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^m$ be a starshaped open subset,and $T$ is a closed current of degree $q$ and order $s$,then there exists a current $S$ of degree $q-1$ and of order $\leq s$,satisfying $dS=T$ on $\Omega$.

The most useful approach to prove this theorem is first show the fact that every closed current is cohomologous to a smooth form. **(A)**

In the proof of **(A)**,he claims **if $\Theta$ and all its derivatives are currents of order $0$, then $\Theta$ is smooth.**

I know currents of order $0$ on manifold can be considered as differential forms with measure coefficients, but how can we get this claim?

Any suggestion and references are appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the definition of "smooth current"?

Comment: @md2perpe，it is smooth differential form.

Comment: what type of "derivative" is being used in "all its derivatives"?

Comment: Also, you might want to swap out one of the tags for [geometric-measure-theory].

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis,thanks for your advice,it's in the sense of weak derivatives.